# Getting GENERAL_ERROR while calling FindObjectsInit function in C# on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: c#

I am using Net.Sf.Pkcs11 DLL to access private key which is stored in eToken.

FindObjectsInit function is working properly with Windows 7 but when I use same code (created in C#) on Windows Server 2008 R2 it is giving me GENERAL_ERROR.

Could you please help me to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is resolved now. This was basically Platform issue. My code was working on 32 bit but it is not working on 64 bit Platform because the vendor of my eToken has provided drive compatible to 32 bit only.

Following steps I have performed to resolve this issue:

1. Change my Project Target Platform to x86.
2. Used the DLL which resides on SysWOW64 folder (This folder contains all the 32 bit DLL on 64 bit OS)